# Is it same to set two subscribers in a Node and set two subscribers in two Nodes?

Tags: python, ros, rospy

I am new for ROS System, i am working on a system that will subscribe two video source and doing some cv stuff with it.

But i am confuse rather should i using two python file(two node) with two different subscribers, or i just use one python file with a class has two different subscribers?

is it same at all? or which way is the better way to define my code?

Thanks!!

and another litter small question... can i know the source of the Image type data? cause i have two Image data to receive, but they have same image size at all. I need to know which one is it to do different process on it, so this is why i use two subscriber in my work

If i use only one subscriber to subscribe two source Image, can i distinguish which one is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is too ambiguous to answer. Implementation specifics are completely dependent on your application and constraints you have. As a general rule, if you think it'll be computationally expensive, you should use two distinct nodes.

Your second question has a much more clear answer. You can access debug info via the `_connection_header` field of a received message.

```
>>> print(some_msg._connection_header)
{'callerid': '/talker_38321_1284999593611',
'latching': '0',
'md5sum': '992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1',
'message_definition': 'string data\n\n',
'topic': '/chatter',
'type': 'std_msgs/String'}
>>> print(some_msg._connection_header['callderid'])
'/talker_38321_1284999593611'
```

I should note that this isn't a recommended beyond use for debugging.